# How to show that the distance between these sets is positive?

Tags: general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces

Let $T_i=\{(1-t)x_i+ty_i;\;0\leq t\leq1\}$, where $x_i,y_i\in\mathbb{R}^n$; $i=1,2$.

Could someone help me  to prove that if $x_2= (1+\varepsilon)x_1$ and $y_2= (1+\varepsilon)y_1$ for some $\varepsilon>0$ then $d\left (T_1,T_2\right)>0$?

Thanks.

Comment: Since both sets are compact, one could as well ask, when the sets are disjoint. Remember: If $A$ is closed and $K$ is compact, then $d(A,K)>0$ if and only if $A$ and $K$ are disjoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you compute the distance? Is it Hausdoff distance? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_distance

So the two sets which you have are segments $I_1, I_2$, both of them connect two points($I_i = [x_i,y_i]$). Consider the case when these segments do not coinside (i.e. the nontrivial one, when at most one pair of endpoints coinsides). Then the other does not, say, $x_1\neq x_2$. Then, if $I_1$ is not contained in $I_2$ (and we may assume without loss of generality that this is the precise case), $d(x_1,I_2) = \inf_{x\in I_2}d(x_1,x)>0$ (in fact one of the segments can be contained in another, but that doesn't change the matters...). And from here you can see that the Hausdorff distance between $I_1$ and $I_2$ is greater than 0 (cf. the link for the formula). So the statement is true whenever your segments do not coinside (they can intersect, or one can contain the other, or they may have no points in common at all)

Comment: mmm, in case when $x_1 = y_1$ the segment $I_1$ becomes a singleton, and if $x_2 = y_2$ also, then $I_2$ becomes a singleton as well, so the distance between them will be nonzero if and only if they are distinct.

Comment: So in fact in your specific case there is at least one pair of endpoints which do not coinside (excluding the trivial case of $x_i = 0 = y_i$ described by Rasmus).

Answer (score 0):

This is false: take $x_i=0$ and $y_i=0$.

Comment: It’s false in far more cases than this, but the segments in question seem to be subsets of rays out of the origin, so you can see when the statement would be true, I ween.

Comment: So, when it's true?

Comment: When $x_1$ and $y_1$ do not lie on the same ray; and also when, the two lying on the same ray, one of them is beyond $(1+\varepsilon)$ times the other.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following holds:

If the point $0\notin T_1$ (where $0\in\mathbb{R}^n$), and $\mathbf{IF}$ the distance is calculated as below $$d(T_1,T_2)=\inf\{d(p_1,p_2):p_1\in T_1,\ p_2\in T_2\}$$ Then we get $$d(T_1,T_2)=\epsilon  \ \inf\{d(p_1,0):p_1\in T_1\}>0$$

Comment: why should it be that way? Consider in $\mathbb{R}^1$ $x_1 = 1, y_1 = 3$, $\varepsilon = 2$, for instance. Then $x_2 = (1+1)1 = 2, y_2 = (1+1)3 = 6$, and, according to your first formula, $d(T_1,T_2) = 0$!

Comment: @AlexWhite, that's according to the distance definition I have adopted. If that's changed, the answer will change. How is the distance calculated in this case?